# How to insert n number of xml node in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

My stored procedure is like this:

```
alter procedure insertxml
   @inxml xml
as

insert into imagess
  (ids, photo, names)
values 
  (@inxml.value('(/imagess/ids)[1]', 'int'),
   @inxml.value('(/imagess/photo)[1]', 'char'),
   @inxml.value('(/imagess/names)[1]', 'varchar(10)'))

exec insertxml '<imagess>
                  <ids>31</ids>
                  <photo>N</photo>
                  <names>30</names>
                  <ids>11</ids>
                  <photo>O</photo>
                  <names>20</names>
                  <ids>12</ids>
                  <photo>A</photo>
                  <names>43</names>
                </imagess>'
```

Through this, I am able to insert a first row only.  I want to insert all 3 rows.

Comment: Your issue is the XML, not the SQL code.

Comment: OMG ponies, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OMG Ponies pointed out in his comment, the XML code needs to be adjusted in order for this to work; however, I think what you're looking for is something like (note the additional tag in the XML):

```
DECLARE @imagess TABLE (ids INT, photo VARCHAR(1), NAMES INT)
DECLARE @inxml XML = '<imagess>
                  <image><ids>31</ids>
                  <photo>N</photo>
                  <names>30</names>
                  </image><image>
                  <ids>11</ids>
                  <photo>O</photo>
                  <names>20</names>
                  </image><image>
                  <ids>12</ids>
                  <photo>A</photo>
                  <names>43</names>
                  </image>
                </imagess>'


insert into @imagess
  (ids, photo, names)
SELECT c.value('(./ids)[1]', 'int'),
   c.value('(./photo)[1]', 'char'),
   c.value('(./names)[1]', 'varchar(10)')
FROM @inxml.nodes('//image') T(c)

SELECT *
FROM @imagess
```